# Docker Nginx does not listen to browser

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

I have this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dz01
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pz01
    ports:
        - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
volumes:
    postgres_database:
        external: true
```

And this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /src
RUN mkdir /static
WORKDIR /src
ADD ./src /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.pip
CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input;python manage.py migrate; gunicorn computationalMarketing.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The web and postgres server does not return an error log, just the success when I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`.
At this moment the three containers are running, but when I go to the browser and navigate to: `localhost:8001` it does not work.

It shows the "connection has been restarted" error message.

Despite that, the web server still does not return any error, so I guess that I have everything properly configurated in my Django app. I really believe that the problem is related to `Nginx`, because when I review the `Nginx log` (using kinematic) it is still empty.

Why wouldn't Nginx be listening to connections?

**Hint:**
This error is happening in a new project. I tried to understand whether I have anything wrong, I'm running an old project and it works perfectly. I tried to copy the working project in my new folder and remove all existent containers and then try to run this old project in a new folder and there is the surprise. It does not work now, despite being an exact copy of the project that works in the other folder...

**EDIT**
In my repo I have a `config/nginx` folder with the `helloworld.conf` file:

```
upstream web {  
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /src/static/; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8001;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

Still with the same error... I do not see any log error.

**Django container log**

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
[2018-11-05 13:00:09 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-11-05 13:00:09 +0000] [8] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (8)
[2018-11-05 13:00:09 +0000] [8] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-11-05 13:00:09 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

Comment: The default nginx image listens to port 80. Adapt your port mapping to it.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you mean in the docker-compose.yml file? Then the correct setting is 8001:80 in the nginx port mappint?

Comment: can you put you nginx conf.d ?

Comment: we need nginx config to help

Comment: @RaoslawSzamszur sorry, I have forgotten it. Now you can find in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You nginx configure should be like:

```
upstream web {  
   ip_hash;
   server web:8000;
}

server {
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://web/;
     }
     listen 8001;
     server_name localhost;
}
```

Comment: I have added my file, it's like yours but still not working

Comment: What error are you getting? You can access the NGINX errors using `docker-compose logs nginx`

Comment: Also, I think PostgreSQL Port is wrong. You need to expose `5432:5432` but you are doing `5433:5432`

Comment: The log only returns: Attaching to nz01. The port is a mapping between localhost and postgresql. It means that Postgresql using 5432 will get petition from localhost through 5433. It works when I connect using DataGrip

Comment: what is your django logs showing `docker-compose logs django`

Comment: it returns: ERROR: No such service: django :S

Comment: I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

Since this kind of problems usually are difficult to debug/reproduce I have created dummy example to just run Django app and serve it via Nginx. You can try to adjust it to your needs. Please forgive me if I have missed something, or done that shouldn't be, but I'm unfamiliar with Django framework.

Dockerfile for Django container:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code && \
    pip install django
WORKDIR /code
ADD helloworld /code
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./helloworld:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
```

config/nginx/django.conf:

```
upstream web {  
   ip_hash;
   server web:8000;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name localhost;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://web/;
     }
}
```

Django app is inside helloworld folder.

For this example, traffic is simply passed. Proper way would be using Unix sockets instead of ports but again I'm unfamiliar with Django.